# Join two tables matching multiple ID's to names

Tags: mysql, database

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53d3c/2/0

I have two tables, one containing Member Names and their ID Number. Let's call that table *Names*:

```
CREATE TABLE Names (
    ID int,
    Title text
);

INSERT INTO Names
VALUES (11,'Chad'),
   (10,'Deb'),
   (34,'Steph'),
   (13,'Chris'),
   (98,'Peter'),
   (33,'Daniel'),
   (78,'Christine'),
   (53,'Yolanda')
;
```

My second table contains meeting information, where someone is a *Coach* and someone is a *Player*. Each entry is a separate line (i.e. Meeting_ID 1 has two entries, one for the coach, one for the participant). Further, there is a column identifier for if that row is for a coach or player.

```
CREATE TABLE Meeting_Data (
    Meeting_ID int,
    Player_ID int,
    Coach_ID int,
    field_id int
);

INSERT INTO Meeting_Data
VALUES (1,0,11,2),
   (1,10,0,1),
   (2,34,0,1),
   (2,0,13,2),
   (3,98,0,1),
   (3,0,33,2),
   (4,78,0,1),
   (4,0,53,2)
;
```

What I'm trying to do is create a table that puts each Meeting on one row, and then puts the ID#s and Names of the people meeting. When I attempt this, I get one column to pull successfully and then one column of (null) values.

```
SELECT Meeting_ID,
   Max(CASE 
         WHEN field_id = 1 THEN Player_ID 
       END) AS Player_ID,
   Max(CASE 
         WHEN field_id = 2 THEN Coach_ID 
       END) AS Coach_ID,
   Player_Names.Title as Player_Names,
   Coach_Names.Title as Coach_Names

FROM   Meeting_Data

LEFT JOIN Names Player_Names
ON Player_ID = Player_Names.ID

LEFT JOIN Names Coach_Names
ON Coach_ID = Coach_Names.ID

GROUP BY Meeting_ID
```

Which results in:

```
| Meeting_ID | Player_ID | Coach_ID | Player_Names | Coach_Names |
|------------|-----------|----------|--------------|-------------|
|          1 |        10 |       11 |          Deb |      (null) |
|          2 |        34 |       13 |        Steph |      (null) |
|          3 |        98 |       33 |        Peter |      (null) |
|          4 |        78 |       53 |    Christine |      (null) |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53d3c/52/0):

```
SELECT Meeting_ID, Player_ID, Coach_ID, Players.Title, Coaches.Title
FROM (
  SELECT Meeting_ID,
  MAX(Player_ID) as Player_ID,
  MAX(Coach_ID) as Coach_ID
  FROM   Meeting_Data
  GROUP BY Meeting_ID
) meeting
LEFT JOIN Names Players ON Players.ID = meeting.Player_ID
LEFT JOIN Names Coaches ON Coaches.ID = meeting.Coach_ID
```

Comment: Miles you are a life saver! Thank you!